# Incorrect origin value. Please set it to - (window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host) of the top-most page

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

```
[Report Only] Refused to frame 'https://docs.google.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors https://docs.google.com".

3760914899-picker_modularized_opc.js:1112 Uncaught Error: Incorrect origin value. Please set it to - (window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host) of the top-most page
    at new KJ (3760914899-picker_modularized_opc.js:1112)
    at 3760914899-picker_modularized_opc.js:1115
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (picker:61)
KJ @ 3760914899-picker_modularized_opc.js:1112
(anonymous) @ 3760914899-picker_modularized_opc.js:1115
(anonymous) @ picker:61
rpc.js?c=1&container=onepick:127 Invalid rpc message origin.  vs https://local.kurzweil3000.com
```

Setting the origin with setOrigin(window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host) in google.picker.PickerBuilder() is not resolving this issue.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: There is a related issue in the Google Tracker: [#203793068](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/203793068)- hopefully a solution will be provided soon 

Answer (score 1):

Refer: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/203793068

Fix:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let saveArrayFrom = Array.from;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Restore native Array.from replaced by prototype.js
    Array.from = saveArrayFrom || Array.from;
    saveArrayFrom = undefined;
</script>
```